# Sveltekit: Error when building my website with adapter-static

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to build my website with adapter-static and I get this error:

```
node:internal/event_target:908
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
TypeError [Error]: param_value.startsWith is not a function
```

The website has several pages but the build problem comes from the blog, since I have added `entries` to the dynamic routes.
Otherwise, the website works properly in development.

So, I have a `/blog` route that is basically a redirect towards `/blog/page/1` :

```js
// File +page.server.js

import {redirect} from '@sveltejs/kit';

export function load() {
    throw redirect(308, '/blog/page/1');
}
```

Then I have a `/blog/page/[number]` route  where I have this entries function :

```js
// File +page.server.js

export let entries = async () => {
    let data = [];
    let pageNumbers = await getPageNumbers();

    for (let i of pageNumbers) {
        data.push({
            number: i
        });
    }

    return data;
}
```

When I log the `data` returned by `entries()` it is fine:

```
[ { number: 1 } ]
```

Any idea of what could be a problem here?

The full error:

```
> vite build


vite v4.3.9 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 75 modules transformed.

node:internal/event_target:908
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
TypeError [Error]: param_value.startsWith is not a function
    at file:///home/georges/dev/cdm-front/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/index.js:140:22
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at file:///home/georges/dev/cdm-front/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/index.js:131:13
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePath (file:///home/georges/dev/cdm-front/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/index.js:130:5)
    at file:///home/georges/dev/cdm-front/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/analyse.js:148:56
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at analyse (file:///home/georges/dev/cdm-front/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/analyse.js:148:34)
    at async MessagePort.<anonymous> (file:///home/georges/dev/cdm-front/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/utils/fork.js:22:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at [kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:289:10)
    at [kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:300:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:201:57)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:639:20)
    at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)

Node.js v18.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The parameter cannot be a number, it has to be a string.

So, I just fixed my `entries()` function:

```js
export let entries = async () => {
    let data = [];
    let pageNumbers = await getPageNumbers();

    for (let i of pageNumbers) {
        data.push({
            number: `${i}`
        });
    }

    return data;
}
```